# replace a key value in array with a new value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a form with this fields in laravel:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name="title">
<input type='file' name="files">
</form>

In server side, I done some proccess on files.

$imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('files'));
```

**dd($imagesUrl):**

```
array:2 [▼
  "images" => array:4 [▼
    "original" => "/upload/images/2017/10453717_202487510125261_45876946_n.jpg"
    300 => "/upload/images/2017/300_10453717_202487510125261_45876946_n.jpg"
    600 => "/upload/images/2017/600_10453717_202487510125261_45876946_n.jpg"
    900 => "/upload/images/2017/900_10453717_202487510125261_45876946_n.jpg"
  ]

  "thumb" => "/upload/images/2017/300_10453717_202487510125261_45876946_n.jpg"
]
```

Now I want replace `$imagesUrl` with `$request->file('files')` and insert new record in database.
I try this:

```
auth()->user()->article()->create(array_merge($request->all() , [ 'files' => $imagesUrl]));
```

But I get this error:

> (1/1) ErrorException Array to string conversion

what is my wrong?

Comment: Do this part on another line and var dump it. `array_merge($request->all() , [ 'files' => $imagesUrl])`. If that generates an error, var dump $request->all(), and $imagesUrl to get a better idea

Comment: I did it. array_merge works fine. value of `files` is an array ..so it retrun Array to String error...but according laravel doc,It must insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I added this code in modal

```
protected $casts = [
  'files' => 'array'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$imagesUrl = serialize($imagesUrl);

$arrInsert = ['title'=> $request->title,'files'=>$imagesUrl];

auth()->user()->article()->create($arrInsert);
```

and retrieve it again and then unserialize

```
$imagesUrl = unserialize($raw->files);
```